# Bing Maps Directions Callback Runs Too Fast?

Tags: javascript, geocoding, bing-maps

When using the Bing Maps Api and doing geocoding I am trying to store the latitude and longitude in arrays from the callback. Mostly this works, except for one usually. There always seems to be a duplicate latitude and longitude in entitiesToVisit, but not testLocations when CalculateOptimizedDirections is called.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < toVisit.length; i++){
        if(toVisit[i].checked){
            var count = parseInt(toVisit[i].id.toString().split(":")[0]);
            var tempEntity = entitiesToPickFrom[count];
            console.log(entitiesToPickFrom[count]);
            tempEntity.compositeAddress = document.getElementById("d"+toVisit[i].id.toString().split(":")[1]).innerHTML.split(">")[1].split("<")[0];
            config.searchManager.geocode({
                where: tempEntity.compositeAddress,
                count: 1,
                callback: function (result, pinData) {
                    var topResult = result.results && result.results[0];
                    if (topResult) {
                        pinData.latitude = topResult.location.latitude;
                        pinData.longitude = topResult.location.longitude;
                        entitiesToPickFrom[count].latitude = topResult.location.latitude;
                        entitiesToPickFrom[count].longitude = topResult.location.longitude;
                        //entitiesToVisit.push(pinData);
                        //setTimeout(10,function (){console.log("Pin Data");});
                        //console.log(entitiesToVisit);
                        document.getElementById("BingMap").style.display = "block";
                        var wizardDiv = document.getElementById("AddressSelectioWizard");
                        wizardDiv.style.display = "none";
                        //possible issue
                        testLocations.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(pinData.latitude,pinData.longitude));
                        entitiesToVisit.push(pinData);
                        //testLocations.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(tempEntity.latitude,tempEntity.longitude));
                        if(entitiesToVisit.length >= checkedCheckers){
                            CalculateOptimizedDirections();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        //console.log("Nothing gotten");
                        console.log(result);
                        //console.log(tempEntity.compositeAddress);
                    }
                },
                errorCallback: function (error){console.log(error)},
                userData: tempEntity
            });

        }
    }
```

I've noticed that when I set a timeout to just print text to the console in the middle of the callback, everything works perfectly. This seems to be a bad solution though, is there a better way around it?

Answer (score 0):

The pinData object you are passing into the entitiesToVisit array is the tempEntity value you are passing into the userData option of the geocode call. The issue is likely related to this code:

```
var count = parseInt(toVisit[i].id.toString().split(":")[0]);
var tempEntity = entitiesToPickFrom[count];
```

Comment: Thank you, while checking that I found an unrelated bug, but the geo-coding results seem good past that point.